# What does it mean by "up about" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I was faced the sentence bellow that is written by a YouTuber:

> New Video up about my favorite productivity tools.

So what does it mean by "up about" or "up" and what does this sentence say?

Answer (score 1):

It is two separate concepts: the video is *up*, and the the video which is up is *about* some topic.

We often say that a piece of media is "up" (as in "uploaded") or "out" (as in "out for distribution") or "released." This means that it is available for public consumption, like on YouTube or iTunes or a movie theater.

The sentence means:

> My new video on the topic of "my favorite productivity tools" is available for viewing.